# Are Holocrons canon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, canon, holocron

I was reading an answer here a few days ago that was talking about "Holocrons", saying that Kylo Ren might have learned the ways of the dark side from a Holocron.

Are these Holocrons actual Star Wars material?  Unless I'm forgetting something major, I don't recall them in any of the films, original or prequel.

How official are these Holocrons?  Did Lucas invent them or discuss them at some point?  If someone else made them up, did he go on record as saying they are a Star Wars "fact"?

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is "canon".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Holocrons are a fully canon part of the Star Wars universe. They're found in the [novelisation for RotS](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)), [Clone Wars TV series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Holocron_Heist), [Star Wars: Rebels TV series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels:_Spark_of_Rebellion) and on the [official Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/holocron) where they're described as:

> *"ancient repositories of knowledge and wisdom that can only be accessed by those skilled in the Force. Both Jedi and Sith use them to record and preserve their teachings, creating a record for future generations seeking to understand the mysteries of the Force"*

[image]

As far as George Lucas' awareness of the existence of holocrons within the Star Wars universe, he was at one point in *daily contact* with Leyland Chee over the creation of a single database of Star Wars canon known as the "Holocron Archive" (now the Databank).

Comment: Hmm, considering how close in time we answered the question, perhaps you too have a [synaptic scanner](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-scifi-stackexchange/7168#7168)

Comment: Nah. I just went and got the appropriate holocron down off the shelf

Comment: Off topic - what's that shot from?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - The Clone Wars TV show. An episode called 'Holocron Heist' if memory serves.

Comment: That's not from The Clone Wars, it's from Rebels! (You can tell from the grass.) Also... Lucas was in *daily contact* with Chee? Meesa no tink so...

Comment: @rasmorthil - I look to be corrected on th the exact provenance of the picture. I grabbed it from wookiepedia. As far as Chee is concerned, I gather that in the very early days of the holocron archive project he was working from Skywalker Ranch.

Comment: Might be worth spelling out where holocrons appear in the films, since OP not remembering them was the motivation here (and I didn't remember either). Was it in the prequel films when Obi-Wan visits the Jedi Archives or something?

Comment: Holocrons *don't* appear in the films, as indicated by N_Soong's answer below, but they do appear in *The Clone Wars* and *Rebels*. They were invented by post-OT EU material. The above picture is from "Spark of Rebellion", the first episode of *Rebels*. Star Wars tends to depict planets as if they have only one type of biome, and Lothal (grassland) is no different.

Answer (score 21):

## Canon Status

**Holocrons are completely canon**.  They are referenced on [StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank/holocron) and [were seen in the series *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* and *Star Wars Rebels*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Holocron/Canon).  So, just to clear up their canonical status, they are fully canon.

## Regarding Lucas

As for their appearance in the movies, it should be noted that according to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Holocron),

> Although not seen in the film, during production of Attack of the
>   Clones, **the film's propmakers made three holocrons** for its Visual
>   Dictionary: a Jedi holocron, a Sith holocron and the Great Holocron.

Now, that Visual Dictionary is Legends (i.e. not canon) but it stands to reason to assume that **Lucas was probably aware of the existence of these holocron props.** Whether Lucas thinks they're canon or not is beside the point now though, as their existence in *The Clone Wars* and *Rebels* confirms the canonical status.

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, they also appear regularly throughout the "Star Wars: The Old Republic" MMO PC game.  It has been a few years since I've played it, but I do recall collecting them.  Not sure on whether SWTOR is canon status or not though...

Comment: @Eckert - None of the SW games are considered canon any more.

Comment: @Richard - so all that time on **Tie Fighter** was wasted?

Comment: @HannoverFist - "Time spent enjoyably is time well spent"